# Python - How to check the place value in a list

Tags: python, arrays, list, input

### Python: List checking

I am trying to write a Python (2.7.3) program that would check a list to see if a the value of a placing for a list has been given or not?

```
input = raw_input("(Enter three numbers separated by commas) >: ")
input_list = input.split(" ")
replacing_letters = [str(x.strip(" ")) for x in input_list]
'if replacing_letters[2] is blank:'
    print"Incomplete"
'elif replacing_letters[2] is full':
    print replacing_letters
```

So if I were to enter three numbers into an input, it would print the list to the user. But say I were to only input two numbers. It would return to the user 'Incomplete'.

Any suggestions on a method or code to accomplish this?

Comment: Hint: check how many items there are in the list

Comment: Aside from the question, don't you want to split on comma?

Answer (score 3):

You can get the length of a list with [the `len()` built-in function](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#len). You can then do a simple check against this:

```
if len(input_list) <= 2:
    ...
else:
    ...
```